# Can an assembly have no version?

Tags: c#

Long story short, if I do this:

```
string myV = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Will something ever be null? I read the msdn and it doesn't specify the `GetName()` and `Version` parts.

Comment: BTW: It should read `Version myV = ...`, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Using ReSharper on `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()?.GetName()?.Version?.Build` it suggests that the first two `?` are redundant (i.e. cannot be null) but not the last `?`.

Comment: @UweKeim, how can you get `null` for `Version`?

Comment: @techspider [See here, below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37600417/107625).

Comment: @UweKeim According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) `GetExecutingAssembly()` _can_ return null.  I'm surprised Resharper would assume that a method that returns a reference type could never return `null`.

Comment: @UweKeim: Is ReSharper doing some sort of static analysis, or is it guessing?  I doubt it can know with 100% that Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() cannot be null.. [This](http://asizikov.github.io/2015/08/16/resharper-annotations-can-it-be-null/) seems to indicate it can be wrong for complex expressions and needs annotation to be sure, so I wouldn't take that as proof.

Comment: @DStanley IIRC, the ReSharper guys did annotate the BCL by themself, on which these suggestions are based. So maybe they did not read the docs completely correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version will always be there.

> Each assembly has a version number as part of its identity.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z(v=vs.110).aspx

By the way, if you are using C#6, in similar cases when not sure about what method returns you should consider using null propogation operator "?.". By doing that you would make sure that it never throws null reference error.

Worst that could happen is that resulting string would be null.

```
string myV = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()?.GetName()?.Version?.ToString();
```

Comment: `Version will always be there` can you expand on that or point out some documentation or something?

Comment: So the ToString() at the end will never fail due to null? Thanks a lot by the way

Comment: Yes. Result would just be null.

Comment: Accepted due to documentation

Answer (score 5):

It's *technically possible* for that field to be null:

```
var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();
name.Version = null;
Console.WriteLine(name.Version == null);   // true
```

But I can't think of any circumstances in which it *would* be null.  Since it's trivial to check I would just add a null check and throw a custom exception if appropriate if it *is* null, since diagnosing a `NullReferenceException` can be difficult because you don't get any indication as to *what* is null other than the stack trace.

Comment: I completely agree with the being-safe-approach, I was just curious because I couldn't find this info anywhere.

Comment: for that sake, you can make null for anything.  The question of being `null` is not by assigning; but by retrieving from Assembly

Comment: @techspider True, but it's such a trivial check there's no harm in it.  I'd rather add two lines of code that identify a completely exceptional circumstance than have to trace through code to diagnose a `NullReferenceException` that _should_ never happen.

Comment: @DStanley, I agree for `NullReference` check; it is one of the standard coding practices.

Comment: No need to add extra lines if you are on C# 6. It is just a matter of adding extra question mark symbol. See my answer for details.